# Layout design for Cards like Multiple Section in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

The below image is the first page from Google I/O 2015 app.

[image]

I Would like to achieve something like this. Each Section in each cards with few details in `RecyclerView` along with `More` Button at top right.

I tried something like,

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/root">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Updates"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/updates">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Videos"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/videos">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

But, I am not sure whether this is correct approach or not. Do we need to use each `RecyclerView` for each section? Suppose, If I have 5 section, then should i have 5 `RecyclerView`?

Comment: You should not use more than one RecyclerViews. You can archive your required design by Sections to your RecyclerView. There are many ways to adding sections to RecyclerView. If you are new then use some library project like https://github.com/afollestad/sectioned-recyclerview

Comment: Yes, he's right, like i said, *it will take a lot of memory* and all of the users can't use it at all.

Comment: @Sharj I had a look at that library. I have multiple array list with custom object and i save those updates, videos, articles data which i get from web service. How can I set a single `recyclerView` for a adapter with having multiple `arrayList`?

Comment: @LinX64 you didn't said anything. But, 'why like i said'?

Comment: I said that in my answer!

Comment: @user3289108 you could create a new Object that stores multiple ArrayLists that you have and pass that to your `RecyclerView` adapter. Remember you don't have to pass an ArrayList, you can pass anything and handle logic in your adapter to required items.

Comment: I'm getting your point. My only problem now is, how and where should i give a break for separating as section. I looked that library. For statically, they are breaking after some count. What if, I get 3 times for one section, 5 for other section and so on? There should be something i should mention to give a break for creating a new section.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use for each section a `RecyclerView`.*but, i think it will take a lot of memory.*

and also, Take them into a `CardView` like this for each section:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Updates"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/updates"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Awaiting for a better solution.

Comment: You should avoid any situation which cases multiple Scrolling.

Comment: @Sharj - yeah, well, that's a good point.i think the best choice is gonna be using the libraries like you said, but, let's see if anyone else has better idea.Thank you for mentioning about it, i didn't think about it :)